# Docker container unable to resolve internet host that docker host can resolve

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

This confuses me as it's *just* started happening...

My workstation (Ubuntu 18.04 running docker 20.10.17) can resolve a specific internet host without issue. The container that my workstation hosts, however, is unable to resolve the same host.

[image: docker container, then host, resolving the same online host]

**Any** other internet host appears to resolve without any issue within the container :  actually, from what I can see, it's unable to resolve any host assigned to that specific domain name (eg flora.com) but *only* in the container - on the host it's just fine.

I've read that docker takes a copy of `/etc/resolv.conf` from the host and places it into the container, but I don't think that's correct as my container's `/etc/resolv.conf` reads as follows:

```
search lan
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options edns0 ndots:0
```

whereas my workstation's `/etc/resolv.conf` read:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
...
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search lan
```

Within my `docker-compose.yml` I have my containers using a defined bridged network (which has been working just fine for the last three years):

```yaml
  console-vpacs:
    ...
    depends_on: [console-mysql]
    ...
    networks:
      - dev-vlt-console
...
networks:
  dev-vlt-console:
    name: dev-vlt-console
    driver: bridge
```

I'm at a bit of a loss where to go from here as I've :

1. restarted the docker service a number of time
2. deleted the docker0 interface, restarted the service
3. searched SO and google and nothing appears to be working (the only thing I've not done is to remove docker and reinstall)

Can anyone give any insight?

Answer (score 0):

A complete reinstall of docker resolved this issue. Very odd that it happened, but I'm still running 20.10.17 so there was no update there ... but I'm back up and running again